# Разница между equals(java) и equalTo(Hamcrest)

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, test-automation, testng, uiautomation

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться в чем разница между

- `equals(java)`
- и `equalTo(Hamcrest)`

как по мне делают одну и туже проверку оба делают сравнение

**Например:**

```
Assert.assertThat(actual, equalTo("test"));
```

делает сравнение на равенства
и

```
String s1 = "Test";
String s2 = "Test";
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

->делает сравнение на равенства

Тоже самое делает сравнивает, зачем тогда нужен `equalTo` если есть `equals`?

Пожалуйста не судите строго.

Comment: Добро пожаловать в сообщество. Если пост, ответил на Ваш вопрос, то см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

## Коротко

- `equals()` сравнивает два объекта и возвращает `true` или `false`
- `equalsTo()` возвращает способ сравнения двух объектов в виде лямбды описанной функциональным интерфейсом `Matcher<T>`

> **λ-выражение** (*лямбда-выражение*) -
> это конструкция, которая помогает определять, передавать и многократно вызывать ряд инструкций описанных в теле выражения.

## Подробно

`equals()` - сравнивает два объекта и дефолтная реализация(`Object.equals()`) сравнивает две ссылки на эти объекты.

В таком виде он имеет не очень много смысла.
Для корректной работы его необходимо переопределять.

И это здорово, когда весь код ты пишешь самостоятельно и можешь всегда написать в случае необходимости нужную реализацию.
**А что если нет?**

И с этим сталкиваются тестировщики, которые не имеют доступа непосредственно к рабочему коду, не могут никак на него повлиять и  часто приходится иметь дело с объектами, которые предоставляются сторонними библиотеками...
**И как им быть?**

И для этого есть тот самый `equalsTo()`, о котором вы спрашивали.
Если вы посмотрите внимательно, то заметите что `equalsTo()` возвращает объекты типа `interface Matcher<T>`.

По своей сути это функциональный интерфейс, и Вы передаете в `Assert.assertThat()` лямбду, которая будет сравнивать два объекта.
То есть вы в `Assert` передаёте инструкции о том, как стоит сравнивать два объекта.
Другими словами вы указываете **ЧТО** и **КАК ИМЕННО** сравнивать.
И как водится, для самых распространенных кейсов (сравнения строк) имеются деволтные реализации и в данном случае два ваших случая идентичны.

Но давать свои плоды оно начинает, когда Вам необходимо сравнивать объекты, на классы которых вы никак повлиять не можете, а сравнивать их приходится.
Тогда и пригождается данный функциональьный интерфейс, который позволяет передать в assert **СПОСОБ СРАВНЕНИЯ ДВУХ ОБЪЕКТОВ**

И так как интерфейс для работы должен быть универсальным для сравнения всех  объектов используется наиболее универсальный и функциональный способ с передачей `Matcher`'a, который может сравнивать объекты данного типа.

Таким способом, Вы сможете решать свои задачи и не зависить от вендоров.

Comment: В основном правильно, но есть неточности и нарушение логики изложения. матчер возвращаемый `Matchers.equalTo` (без `s` кстати) всегда сравнивает объекты с помощью метода `equals`, так что тестировщики не могут подменить способ сравнения используя `equalTo`. Главное в матчерах это возможность проверять разные условия в тестах,  комбинировать условия используя связки, получать читаемые сообщения когда условие не совпадает (что ожидали, что получили - и опять же для составных матчеров это получаем автоматом), и последнее - более читаемый код теста. Ну а `equalTo` - это самый простой из матчеров.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, спасибо за комментарий и замечание. Сегодня сил уже нет на SO сидеть, но завтра чуть внимательнее прочитаю, ресёрч еще небольшой проведу и обновлю ответ. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA...да, там по сути отдельно только кейс с массивами разбирается в реализации `IsEqual.equalTo()`, все остальное на откуп `equals()` отдаётся... с остальным завтра разберусь

Comment: Ну и с причино - следственными связями понятно что тут поправить надо.

Answer (score 0):

`equals` - это публичный метод класса `Object` и как следствие - всех его наследников. Т.е. метод `equals` есть у абсолютно любого созданного Вами объекта. Как он работает - зависит от Вас (переопределяли Вы его или нет).

`equalTo` - это метод, который создал для какого-то своего класса такой же программист как и Вы. Т.е. Вы можете им пользоваться, если создаете объекты класса о котором сейчас идет речь (например, это может быть какой-нибудь библиотечный класс). Объекты других классов (не потомков этого) не смогут использовать этот метод

Comment: мне кажется вы не о том `equalTo` говорите

Comment: речь о `org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo`